# express-http-proxy still gets blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, proxy, polymer

I have an express server statically serving my Polymer project. I have a REST API query that I need to make, but if I make it from the client it will be blocked by CORS. So I used [express-http-proxy](http://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy) to try to get around that; I send my request to it, and it redirects to the server that has the REST API endpoint on it. This is the entirety of my server code that's running with `node server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

var server = express();
server.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));
server.listen(8080);
server.use('/rest/api/2/search', proxy('restserver:8877'));
console.log("Server listening on localhost:8080");
```

When I access restserver:8877/rest/api/2/search in a browser it returns a bunch of json as a 'default' search.

On the client side, I have iron-ajax making this request:

```
<iron-ajax
            id="getBugs"
            url="/rest/api/2/search"
            params=''
            on-response="handleResponse"
            debounce-duration="300">
        </iron-ajax>
```

And in the script section, I'm using `this.$.getBugs.generateRequest()` in the `ready` function to send the request. So I load this up, expecting the request to not be blocked by CORS, since... it's being proxied by the server. Instead, Chrome devtools gives me this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://restserver:8877/secure/MyJiraHome.jspa. Redirect from 'http://restserver:8877/secure/MyJiraHome.jspa' to 'http://restserver:8877/secure/Dashboard.jspa' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I don't understand why it's giving me those URLs, since I never reference them, and why it's blocking due to CORS, since it's going from the server, not the client, that being the whole point of the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that `express-http-proxy` simply forwards the `Origin` header coming from your client which is `http://localhost:8080`, causing the end server to reject it.

Try modifying it with [`proxyReqOptDecorator`](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy#proxyreqoptdecorator--supports-promise-form):

```js
server.use('/rest/api/2/search', proxy('restserver:8877', {
  proxyReqOptDecorator(proxyReqOpts) {
    proxyReqOpts.headers['Origin'] = 'http://accepted.origin.com';
    return proxyReqOpts;
  }
}));
```

Never used `express-http-proxy` and did not test it tho, so tell me if it's not a solution. Also I think using [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) as other people suggested may simplify things a lot. But I don't know your development constraints, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks this does seem to fix any CORS issues. Unfortunately the `cors` package isn't compatible with express-http-proxy and that's why these headers need to be manually set.

Comment: Glad it worked @FezVrasta Concerning the `cors` package, it's not something you have to plug into `express-http-proxy`. It's a standalone middleware allowing you on the target server, to accept requests from a curated list of hosts like so `app.use(cors(['http://localhost:8080', 'https://www.mywebsite.com']))`. It may be useful and simpler if your problem is *only* your api server rejecting requests from your frontend.

Comment: In my case I'm using the Node.js server to proxy a second REST API so I can't just use the cors package.

Answer (score -1):

Server is probably returning a `302` redirect which is not handled correctly in the used middleware.

Read more how the redirect works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

You can modify the `Location` response header to overcome the CORS issue or you can try:

```
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

var restServerProxy = proxy({target: 'http://restserver:8877', autoRewrite: true});

server.use('/rest/api/2/search', restServerProxy);
```

The above example should handle redirects automatically.

Comment: OP is asking about express-http-proxy, not http-proxy-middleware

Answer (score -1):

You don't need any proxy. Since you are calling endpoint on your server, you can just whitelist your client side for calling your server. You can do that with `cors` package.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors
```

First, define your CORS policy logic in one file (let's name it `cors-policy-logic.js`), and then export it so you can use it in other files.

```
const cors = require('cors');

const whitelist = ['http://localhost:8080', 'http://localhost:your_client_url'];

var corsOptionsDelegate = (req, callback) => {
  var corsOptions;
  if (whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
    corsOptions = { origin: true };
  } else {
    corsOptions = { origin: false };
  }
  callback(null, corsOptions);
};

exports.cors = cors();
exports.corsWithOptions = cors(corsOptionsDelegate);
```

Now, import it and use it anywhere were you define some endpoint:

```
var express = require('express');
const cors = require('./cors-policy-logic.js');

var server = express();
server.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));
server.listen(8080);

server.route('/rest/api/2/search')
  .options(cors.corsWithOptions, (req, res) => { res.sendStatus(200); })
  .get(cors.cors, (req, res, next) => {
     //Your business logic
  });

console.log("Server listening on localhost:8080");
```

Comment: OP is trying to proxy a second server, that’s why they used the proxy package. Your reply doesn’t answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

Alternative solution would be to use **http-proxy-middleware** as mentioned by @chimurai.

If you want to proxy to an **https** server to avoid CORS:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

app.use('/proxy', proxy({
    pathRewrite: {
       '^/proxy/': '/'
    },
    target: 'https://server.com',
    secure: false
}));
```

Here **secure: false** needs to be set to avoid **UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE** error.

Comment: express-http-proxy and http-proxy-middleware are 2 difference things. You can't resolve  express-http-proxy problem with http-proxy-middleware